# quoted string not properly terminated

Tags: sql, linux, oracle

I am using simple insert statement to insert value to CLOB varaible, anyway i am getting that error ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated.

I tried to write value in single line but i had another error that i can't use mroe that 2500 character in the line.

When i separated lines to be less than 2500 , i faced that error ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated.

I used the following statement

```
INSERT INTO table(USER_PROFILE
,NA_TO
)VALUES(
'oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
');
```

Comment: No , i just separated the line as example ,
'oooooooooooooooooooooooooo
\n ooooooooooooooooooooo
\n ooooooooooooooooooooooooo', where \n is new line.

Comment: Revised comment: Have you tried writing the long string as multiple strings using a concatenation function (sometimes available as `CONCAT`) or operator (SQL-92 standard `||`, SQL Server `+`, etc.)?

Comment: I tried now Oracle  operator || but not working either , if you could please ,can give me example of using CONCAT , I am using ORACLE

Comment: in your example you didn't give a value for one of the columns, is it like that in your code ? another thing, are you using sqlplus ?

Comment: Does your example also fail with a short value, eg with just one `o` instead of your very large number? If it does, please reduce your example failing code - see [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Thanks for help Chuck ,i used || , as indicated below and it worked , many thanks for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try writing the long string as multiple strings using your available concatenation function (sometimes available as `CONCAT`) or concatenation operator (SQL-92 standard `||`, SQL Server `+`, etc.). That way you can avoid these errors because no individual string literal needs to be very long.

Also, you must provide a value for each column that you list. On the other hand you are not required to list all of the columns in the table.

```
INSERT INTO table(USER_PROFILE, NA_TO) VALUES(
'oooooooooo' || 'oooooooooo' || 'oooooooooo' || 'oooooooooo' || 'oooooooooo' || 
'oooooooooo' || 'oooooooooo' || 'oooooooooo' || 'oooooooooo' || 'oooooooooo' || 
'oooooooooo' || 'oooooooooo' || 'oooooooooo' || 'oooooooooo' || 'oooooooooo' || 
'oooooooooo' || 'oooooooooo' || 'oooooooooo' || 'oooooooooo' || 'oooooooooo' || 
'oooooooooo' || 'oooooooooo' || 'oooooooooo' || 'oooooooooo' || 'oooooooooo' || 
<many more lines like those>
'oooooooooo' || 'oooooooooo' || 'oooooooooo' || 'oooooooooo' || 'oooooooooo',
null)
```